How to write controllers for a new type of wheel arrangement
A little bit about myself and the project:
I am currently doing my bachelors in mechanical engineering and have no formal training in robotics.
The project is lead by a final year student. It has an omni wheel arrangement which I couldn't find any articles or papers about.
The pictures of the wheel arrangement .
The hardware of the bot is already manufactured. Now I am tasked with figuring out how to run this bot. I have to figure out individual velocities that are needed to be provided to each wheel so that the bot performs a specific movement like simple translation in the plane or a rotation about a axis etc.
The problem is neither me nor anyone on the team has had enough training to figure this out. Like the center of mass is quite skewed away from the geometric center and from what I have seen there's no way to apply the no slip condition on the omni wheels.
So I am setting this target that I should be able to achieve only two things:

That the robot should be able to translate in a straight line in both the principal directions. This thing is quite obvious and achievable, we just have to provide equal velocities to the diagonally opposite wheels and keep the other set of diagonal wheels with 0 velocity.

The robot should be able to rotate about its geometric center axis. This is the real challenge. Since I am not able to assume the no slip condition, I cannot kinematically write the velocity relations.


Is there a way so that the bot figures out by itself the best velocities to provide to each wheel so that it achieves this rotation about the geometric center axis. We can add any sensor that is necessary to achieve this. Also another problem with the omni wheel arrangement is that we are not able to simulate the omni wheel movement on gazebo accurately. So I am looking at some kind of machine learning models. Running complex algorithms on the bot won't be a problem as we are going to fit a whole pc with intel i7 core processor on it.
Thanks in advance,
Kindly ask if something isn't clear from my post.
